# Cтатические блоки в классах

Tags: классы, java

Зачем в разделе описания полей классов инициализация в статических блоках? Если поле объявлено в статическом блоке, как к нему обратиться?

Comment: В тегах написана Java, видимо Java.

Answer (score 2):

Если я не ошибаюсь, при создании объекта класса сначала выполняются статические блоки, а потом только вызывается конструктор. А если поле объявлено в статическом блоке, то обратится к нему можно только в этом блоке. Это тоже самое, что вы не сможете обратится к переменной, объявленной в одном методе, в другом.

Comment: Статические блоки вызываются при инициализации класса.

Comment: Понятно, всем спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Обратиться можно через объект, но лучше - через имя класса: MyClass.staticField

Инициализация статических полей в статическом блоке используется если требуется более сложная логика, чем простое присваивание (инициализация при определении).

Comment: Речь идёт не о статических полях, а о блоках.